# Non-solvable non-simple groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Is there any classification of finite non-solvable non-simple groups? (I mean finite groups which are neither solvable nor simple.)

Comment: Basically you are asking for a classification of all finite groups (for any $G\not=1$ $G\times A_5$ is neither soluble nor simple.) That's too much to ask at present.

Comment: If a finite group $H$ contains a non-abelian simple group then $H$ is non-solvable (as If $K$ is finite and simple then $[K, K]=K$). So then the problem is to understand those groups which contain no non-abelian simple subgroups (it would be convenient if they are always solvable!).

Comment: All finite groups have been classified, but this is still an off-topic question for M.SE.

Comment: @AdrianKeister:  do you mean all finite *simple* groups?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh, yes, my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

No, and there is zero hope there will ever be one. Take for example a group of type $G=P \times S$, where $P$ is a $p$-group and $S$ is a non-abelian simple group. To find every $G$ of this type you would first need to find (or classify) all $p$-groups.

Comment: To be fair, if someone proved that "every example has the form $G=P\times S$ where $P$ is a $p$-group and $S$ a non-abelian simple group" then that would count as a "classification"! [I know that there *are* other examples, but my point is that reducing a classification to a black-box classification is, arguably, a classification.]

Comment: I get your point but I think it depends a little on what your focus is. For example, arguing like this we could say that we have classified nilpotent groups because these are simply direct products of $p$-groups. What we have really classified though is their internal structure. You'd be hard-pressed to give me the full list of nilpotent groups of order $2^{20} \cdot 3^{50}$...